how to guarantee that stages don’t drop elements when first upstream errors arrive (and break computation)
Question1: i have a reactive code, this is an example: i need to divide 100 for each number in list and i don't want to break a computation when "divide by zero" happens. I want to proceed to next number untill all numbers in list  was consumed. How a can modify it for accomplish this?
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    CompletionStage<Integer> future = ReactiveStreams.fromIterable(list)
            .map(i -> 100 / i)
            .collect(Collectors.summingInt(i -> i))
            .run();
    future.whenComplete((res, err) -> {
        if (err != null) {
            System.out.println("error " + err);
        } else
            System.out.println("res: " + res);
        });

Console result:
error java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Question 2: I replaced the previous code with this similar one (below), but using mutiny librarym and i want to accomplish the same result, but the same thing happens: the first error break the computation and after the numer 5 the computation stop. How to fix this? This is the code:
Multi.createFrom().items(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10)
                .onRequest().invoke(req -> System.out.println("Got a request: " + req))
                .onItem().transform(i -> 100/i)
                .subscribe().withSubscriber(new Flow.Subscriber<Integer>() {

                                                private Flow.Subscription subscription;

                                                @Override
                                                public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription s) {
                                                    this.subscription = s;
                                                    s.request(1);
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onNext(Integer item) {
                                                    System.out.println("Got item " + item);
                                                    subscription.request(1);
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                                                    System.out.println("error " + t);
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete() {
                                                    System.out.println("finish");
                                                }
                                            }
                );

Console output:
   Got a request: 1 //1
    Got item 100
    Got a request: 1 //2
    Got item 50
    Got a request: 1 //3
    Got item 33
    Got a request: 1 //4
    Got item 25
    Got a request: 1 //5
    Got item 20   // 100/5 =20
    Got a request: 1 //0! and the stop
    error java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero


The error of division is trivial because can be a casual events..For example it can be a call to n http links and one goes in error. i want to simulate a situation that could be happens..but i would IGNORE if it happens..

I'll try use
.onFailure().recoverWithItem(0) but after that it completes and stop instead of continue!
Got a request: 1
Got item 100
Got a request: 1
Got item 50
Got a request: 1
Got item 33
Got a request: 1
Got item 25
Got a request: 1
Got item 20
Got a request: 1
Got item 0
finish

Code:
Multi.createFrom().items(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10)
                .onRequest().invoke(req -> System.out.println("Got a request: " + req))
                .onItem().transform(i -> 100/i)
                .onFailure().recoverWithItem(0) 
                .subscribe().withSubscriber(new Flow.Subscriber<Integer>() {

                                                private Flow.Subscription subscription;

                                                @Override
                                                public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription s) {
                                                    this.subscription = s;
                                                    s.request(1);
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onNext(Integer item) {
                                                    System.out.println("Got item " + item);
                                                    subscription.request(1);
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                                                    System.out.println("error " + t);
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete() {
                                                    System.out.println("finish");
                                                }
                                            }
                );

Thanks
Roby

something divided by 0 is mathematically not defined.

@BIBOOunit onErrorContinue is only for reactor? I  found .onFailure().recoverWithItem(funtion) for questio2 :https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/latest/tutorials/handling-failures/#recovering-using-fallback-items
I dont find nothing for ReactiveStreams for now..

@BIBOOunit  i edit my post because .onFailure().recoverWithItem(0) dont work: it fails but completes and stop computation,..

I think this is one of the approach but if there are two error doesn't work beacause it must be set for each stream but how many times (we dont know..!!)
.

onFailure().recoverWithMulti to send ramained inputs to another multi

Multi.createFrom().items(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10)
            .onRequest().invoke(req -> System.out.println("Got a request: " + req))
            .onItem().transform(i -> 100/i)
            .onFailure().recoverWithMulti(Multi.createFrom().items(7, 8, 9, 10).onItem().transform(i -> 100/i)
            .subscribe().withSubscriber(new Flow.Subscriber<Integer>() {

                                            private Flow.Subscription subscription;

                                            @Override
                                            public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription s) {
                                                this.subscription = s;
                                                s.request(1);
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onNext(Integer item) {
                                                System.out.println("Got item " + item);
                                                subscription.request(1);
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                                                System.out.println("error " + t);
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete() {
                                                System.out.println("finish");
                                            }
                                        });

Output:
Got a request: 1
Got item 100
Got a request: 1
Got item 50
Got a request: 1
Got item 33
Got a request: 1
Got item 25
Got a request: 1
Got item 20
Got a request: 1
Got item 14
Got item 12
Got item 11
Got item 10

Or i can use filter(n -> n!=0)
Multi.createFrom().items(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10)
.filter(n -> n!=0)
.onRequest().invoke(req -> System.out.println("Got a request: " + req))
.onItem().transform(i -> 100/i)
            .onFailure().recoverWithMulti(Multi.createFrom().items(7, 8, 9, 10).onItem().transform(i -> 100/i)
            .subscribe().withSubscriber(new Flow.Subscriber<Integer>() {

                                            private Flow.Subscription subscription;

                                            @Override
                                            public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription s) {
                                                this.subscription = s;
                                                s.request(1);
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onNext(Integer item) {
                                                System.out.println("Got item " + item);
                                                subscription.request(1);
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                                                System.out.println("error " + t);
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete() {
                                                System.out.println("finish");
                                            }
                                        });

